# For two cyclic groups $\phi:C_4 \to C_3$ with $x^i \mapsto y^i$, we have $\phi(x^4)=\phi(x^0)=e$ but also $\phi(x^4) = y^4=y$. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $\phi$ be some function between two cyclic groups of order 4,3 $C_4 =\langle x\rangle $, $C_3 = \langle y\rangle $; $\phi:C_4 \to C_3$, with $\phi(x^i) = y^i$.

Clearly, $x^4 = x^0$, so $\phi(x^4) = y^0 = e$ but by the definition of the function, $\phi(x^4) = y^4 = y$.

My interpretation of the two ways to read $\phi(x^4)$ is clearly leading to a contradiction, and I know the proper reading is $\phi(x^4) = e$, but why isn't $\phi(x^4) = y^4 = y$ implied by the definition? Is it simply a mathematical convention to substitute the input of $\phi$, i.e., $\phi(x^4)$ to $\phi(x^0)$ before evaluating $\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows that $\phi$ cannot be a function. Indeed

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x^4)&=y^4\\
&=y
\end{align}$$

while

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x^4)&=\phi(e)\\
&=\phi(x^0)\\
&=y^0\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

These are two distinct values of $\phi(x^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This answers the question before it was edited to assert that $y$ is a generator of target $C_3$.

---

This calculation shows that if $\phi$ is going to be a well-defined homomorphism, then we must have $y = e$. In other words, the image of the generator $x$ of $C_4$ *has to* map to the identity. This is only a contradiction if you previously assumed that, say $y$ was a generator of $C_3$. You don't have to! Just let $y$ be defined as the image $\phi(x)$.

By the way, this shows that any homomorphism $C_4 \to C_3$ must be the trivial one, mapping all elements of $C_4$ to $e \in C_3$.

Comment: But $x\mapsto y$, and $y$ is a generator.

Comment: Yes, $x \mapsto y$, and you've shown that $y$ is another name for $e$.

Comment: What you've proved is this: if $\phi$ sends a generator of $C_4$ to a generator of $C_3$, then $\phi$ cannot be a homomorphism. Or perhaps more colloquially, "There is no homomorphism from $C_4$ to $C_3$ sending a generator of the first to a generator of the second."

Comment: Yes, either it's a homomorphism so $y$ cannot be a generator and the map is trivial **or** $y$ is a generator and the map cannot be a homomorphism. But they cannot both be true at once!

Comment: Please delete (or significantly edit) this.

Answer (score 1):

If $C_n = \langle x \rangle$, and $\phi \colon C_n \to G$ is a group homomorphism, then
$$ 
1 = \phi(1) = \phi(x^n) = \phi(x)^n,
$$
so the order of $\phi(x)$ divides $n$.

This shows that in order to define a group homomorphism with domain a cyclic group of order $n$, we must send a generator of the cyclic group to an element of the codomain whose order divides $n$.

Hence, if we send a generator of $C_4$ to a generator of $C_3$, this *does not* define a group homomorphism.

Comment: Also a very helpful answer, thank you!